# Unity asset not behaving in blender but does in other software - fixable?

Tags: .fbx

So i have this asset that originates from a unity project.
It is a FBX model with a couple animations, the character is in three mesh parts and some of the meshes deform upon import into Blender.

[image]

Now I have tried to import it in 3DS Max and it do not deform there but gives error messages at the start which can be ignored and it works.
So do anybody know what and if there is anything i can do to fix it to be able to work in blender?
If i knew what makes it deform or maybe re export it out of 3DS if it salvageable.

I can post the error messages 3ds spits out if it would help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's way better to post images inline on Blender Stack Exchange so that people who read your question don't have to click away to some other site. I edited your question and fixed the image - I hope you don't mind. Maybe some more people see it and will come up with more solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

FBX format has problems in Blender because of some issues with license incompatibilities making the importers difficult to maintain if I understand it correctly so if you can use 3ds Max or Unity to convert the asset to some other format like .dea or .abc ir might work fine/better when imported to Blender.